# Have "pure" multisets been studied before?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, multisets

A multiset is a pair $(S, f)$ where $S$ is a (ZFC) set and $f$ a function $f:S \to \mathbb{N}$ which assigns to each $x \in S$ a natural number denoting its multiplicity.

This is fine, but we're still defining multisets in terms of standard set theory.

Has "pure" multi-set theory been studied before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's been studied extensively, to my knowledge, but this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093634995) approaches the subject by surveying the literature, defining a first-order theory, and proving relative consistency with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.